# How to access Rabbitmq Management UI by using fully qualified server name address?

Tags: url, rabbitmq, fully-qualified-naming

How to access Rabbitmq Management UI by using fully qualified server name address? It is working with localhost, but not with server fully qualified name.

Comment: What do you mean for "How to access Rabbitmq Management UI by using fully qualified server name address?" , Can you explain more in detail the problem?